# Memory allocation after declaration of extern class variable

Tags: c

I have read in multiple places that when declaring an extern variable, the memory is not designated until the definition is made. I was trying this code which is giving contradictory output in gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    extern int a;
    printf("%lu", sizeof(a));
    return 0;
}
```

it should have shown error or zero size. but the output was following. please justify the output. Is it example of another undefined behavior?

```
aditya@theMonster:~$ ./a
4
```

Comment: You're just outputting the size of a type. That's perfectly valid. Are you sure you understand what sizeof does?

Comment: @AdityaGaddhyan: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score and upvote those that helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size_t sizeof(expr/var_name/data_type)` 1 is a unary operator which when not provided with a variable length array, do not evaluate the expression. It just check the data type of expression.

Similarly, here, in `sizeof(a)`, the complier only checks the data type of `a` which is `int` and hence returns the size of `int`.

Another example to clear your confusion is in `sizeof(i++)`, i do not get incremented. Its data type is checked and returned.

One more example:

```
void main(){
   int p=0;
   printf("%zu",sizeof(p=2+3.0));
   printf("%d",p);
}
```

will give u output on gcc as:

```
4
0
```

Answer (score 3):

You're able to get away with it here because `a` is never actually used.  The expression `sizeof(a)` is evaluated at compile time.  So because `a` is never referenced, the linker doesn't bother looking for it.

Had you done this instead:

```
printf("%d\n", a);
```

Then the program would have failed to link, printing "undefined reference to `a'"

Answer (score 2):

The size of a variable is the size of its data type, whether it is presently only an `extern` or not. Since `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, whereas symbol resolution is done at link time, this is acceptable.

Even with `-O0`, gcc doesn't care that it's `extern`; it puts `4` in `esi` for the argument to `printf`: https://godbolt.org/z/Zv2VYd

Without declaring `a`, however, any of the following will fail:

```
a = 3;
printf("%d\n", a);
int *p = &a;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `a` is an integer, so its size is 4.

Its *location*(address) and *value* are not currently known.
(it is `extern` somewhere at some other location)

But the *size* is well defined.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a problem in your code, but not where you expect it:

- passing a value of type `size_t` for `printf` conversion specification `%ld` has undefined behavior if `size_t` and `unsigned long` have different sizes or representations, as is the case on many systems (16-bit systems, Windows 64-bit...).

Here is a corrected version, portable to non C99-conforming systems, whose C library `printf` might not support `%zu`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    extern int a;
    printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)sizeof(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding why the program compiles and executes without an error:

- Variable `a` is declared inside the body of `main` with `extern` linkage: no space is allocated for it and `a` would be undefined outside the body of `main`.
- `sizeof(a)` is evaluated at compile time as the constant value `sizeof(int)`, which happens to be `4` on your platform.
- No further reference to `a` is generated by the compiler, so the linker does not complain about `a` not being defined anywhere.